# Dart Mockito: Как протестировать вызов метода с одно класса в другом?

Tags: mockito, dart, flutter

Пробую писать тесты в [Flutter](https://flutter.io/) используя [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/).
Есть класс *Представления* и есть класс *Презентера*. Так вот, мне нужно протестировать при вызове метода *Презентера* (**presenter.loadContacts()**), вызовется ли метод *Представления* (**view.onLoadContactsComplete**):

```
class MockView extends Mock implements ContactListViewContract {

  @override
  void onLoadContactsComplete(List<Contact> items) {

  }
  @override
  void onLoadContactsError() {}

}

void main() {

  test('ContactListPresenter test', () {
    Injector.configure(Flavor.MOCK);
    MockView view = new MockView();

    ContactListPresenter presenter = new ContactListPresenter(view);

    presenter.loadContacts();

    verify(view.onLoadContactsComplete).called(1);

  });

}
```

Это не рабочий/неверный код.

Как правильно тестировать?

Answer (score 1):

1) Убрать оверрайды на MockView. Поведение моков задается с помощью when, а не оверрайдами.

```
class MockView extends Mock implements ContactListViewContract {}
```

2) в verify надо указать не адрес ф-ции, а ее вызов с аргументами

```
verify(view.onLoadContactsComplete(any)).called(1);
```

Comment: Решил проблему - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48293314/how-to-verify-to-call-or-not-to-call-a-method